# Guardar puntos geográficos, en el controller, error en ajax

Tags: mysql, jquery, laravel, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo algunos puntos en el mapa, que se cargan mediante una petición Ajax.

En mi controlador tengo esto:

```
public function recogerForm(Request $request)
{

    $marker = new Marker;
    $marker->name = $request->nombre;
    $marker->address = $request->direccion;

    $marker->idG = $request->idG;

    $pos = strpos($request->LatLng, ',');
    $latitud = substr($request->LatLng, 1, $pos-1);
    $longitud = substr($request->LatLng, $pos+1,strlen($request->LatLng));

    $marker->lat = $latitud;
    $marker->lng = $longitud;
    $marker->idMarker = '1';//$request->id;

    $marker->save();

    return $request;
}
```

En mi ruta tengo lo siguiente:

```
Route::post('/bus','MapaProcesarController@recogerForm');
```

En mi js:

```
 function save_marker(marker, place, i) {
//Save new marker using jQuery Ajax
var mLatLang = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(); //get marker position
var myData = { id: i, name: place.name, address: place.vicinity, latlong: mLatLang, idG: place.id }; //post variables
console.log(myData);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/bus",
  data: myData,
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
  success: function (data) {

    var url = "/guardar";
    $form = $('<form class="formMapa" action="' + url + '" method="post"></form>')
    $form.append('<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="' + $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') + '">');
    $form.append('<input type="text" name="nombre" class="' + "nombre" + data.id + '"/>');
    $form.append('<input type="text" name="direccion" class="' + "direccion" + data.id + '"/>');
    $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="LatLng" class="' + "LatLng" + data.id + '"/>');
    $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="idG" class="' + "idG" + data.id + '"/>');
    $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="idMarker" class="' + "idMarker" + data.id + '"/>');

    $form.append('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Seleccionar" /><br>');
    $('.preForm').append($form);


    $(".nombre" + data.id).val(data.name);
    $(".direccion" + data.id).val(data.address);
    $(".LatLng" + data.id).val(data.latlong);
    $(".idG" + data.id).val(data.idG);
    $(".idMarker" + data.id).val(data.id);
    //console.log(myData);         

  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
  }
});
```

Cuando trato de insertar en mi base de datos el Ajax me marca error si le quito en el controlador el código de insertar en base de datos y sólo dejo

> return request

, no me marca error, a qué es debido, por qué no puedo guardar todos los puntos en mi base de datos? en cambio si no los guardo no tengo problemas?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: "Internal Server Error", es el alert que tengo puesto en este trocito de código: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
  }

Comment: Significa que hay un error en el código del servidor. Por el más mínimo fallo que exista (hasta que olvides cerrar una línea con `;`) da ese tipo de errores. Debes revisar el código del servidor.

Comment: no pero el problema es que si yo a mi controlador le quito todo el código de guardar datos y le dejo solo el return $request, ya no me sale error, es a la hora de guardar los datos, no lo entiendo, no se supone que en mi controlador recogerForm(Request $request) debería tener todos los puntos geográficos?toda la respuesta del ajax? es más si comento el return $request, la vista no me muestra los formularios...

Comment: ya está solucionado, se ve que Laravel no se actualizaba bien y se quedó pillado. Ya me guarda todos los puntos.